# Spark Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I m trying to run Spark on Kubernetes as Scheduler.

It works fine when running from outside of kubernetes cluster using `kubectl proxy`.

```
spark-shell --master k8s://http://localhost:8001 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=abdoumediaoptimise/spark
```

But whenever we try running spark-shell or spark-submit from within a pod directly , it never works (even by following [rbac from spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#rbac) with : 
`--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark` . 
We have authorization execution exception:

> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: https://kubernetes/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?labelSelector=spark-app-selector%3Dspark-application-1574714537374,spark-role%3Dexecutor. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

Any idea how to Launch Spark from within pods ? this actually makes using spark k8s:// with notebooks impossible

Spark RBAC YAML file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name:  spark
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: spark
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: edit
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: spark
    namespace: default
```

Comment: Make sure you ran the following commands in the documentation against your kubectl to have created the required service account and cluster role binding. `kubectl create serviceaccount spark` and `kubectl create clusterrolebinding spark-role --clusterrole=edit --serviceaccount=default:spark --namespace=default`

Comment: @PhilippeHaussmann I did, but still not working

Comment: Could you share your `yaml` manifests of the appropriate `clusterrolebinding` and `serviceaccount` ?

Comment: @mario I applied with kubectl instructions from Philippe above

Comment: Do you get the same error message after applying it ? The message you quoted points out the cause of the issue quite precisely and is rather self-explanatory.

Comment: @mario - yes same message

Comment: So it means that serviceaccount and/or clusterrolebinding still isn't configured properly.

Comment: @mario - I recreated ServiceAccount manually plus clusterBingding to "Edit" ClusterRole. I checked the authorizations of spark serviceAccount using `kubectl auth can-i list --as `system:serviceaccount:default:spark`. spark serviceAccount has rights for list, create, watch pods in the default namespace.

Comment: But as you can see in error messages it doesn't use serviceaccount `spark` but `default`: `User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"`.

Answer (score 0):

`spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName` - is the ServiceAccount name which Spark Driver's Kubernetes client uses to authenticate to Kubernetes API to request executors.

You are looking for `spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.*`, which are used to configure Kubernetes client of `SparkSubmit` application to authenticate to the Kubernetes API to request Service, ConfigMap and Driver Pod.

To make it work configure your Pod with the ServiceAccount of interest:
`spec.serviceAccountName: <your-SA>`. After that use the mounted to the `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount` directory files inside a Pod to configure the `spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.*` options.

Comment: I have 3 files under `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount : ca.crt namespace and token`. I used ca.crt for  `spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile`, still not successfull, I m going through spark docs again

Comment: Try to set as well `spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthTokenFile=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`. And be sure that ServiceAccount configured for your Pod has enough privileges to create Pods, Services, ConfigMaps.

Comment: @Abba did the above solution work for you? If so, would you mind upvoting and accepting it?
Otherwise it would be great to hear if you found another solution.

Comment: @Nightscape - this solution did not help unfortunately. The missing piece was that while creating the deployment of our Pods, We should assign the created service account to the pod service account name